# how to make email id as optional in customer registration and checkout

Tags: magento2, customer

Instead of email, we have used mobile number for the unique field. so we need to make email optional. please answer me, anyone, if you know

Comment: you have to try this free extension `https://marketplace.magento.com/sparsh-magento-2-login-with-mobile-number-extension.html`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.